# Python: is a Python function equivalent to a Python object?

Tags: python

I was experimenting with Python, and tried out an example and it worked.

```
def foo():
    print 'hello world'

foo.a = True
```

So it looks to me foo is an object though it looks like a function.
What is the technical term for it, and what are the use-cases of it?

Comment: Python functions are objects *too*.

Comment: plz google "function attributes" ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen Ya, it has a technical term, I was looking for same, thnx..:-)

Answer (score 1):

[Everything is an object](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/odbchelper_objects.html). At least almost everything. There are very few things in Python in which you can not create attributes. Probably only some of the things that are implemented in C and exposed as Python objects, as they may be not supporting the necessary interface. For example, you can not create attributes inside objects of type `int`, for it does not have a dictionary of attributes (mostly due to performance reasons, I suppose). But it still is an object, though with limited functionality.

Comment: Name one thing that's not!

Comment: @holdenweb: keywords such as `in`, `with`, and `return` are not objects.

Comment: @unutbu are they things?

Comment: Gentlemen, names are references to objects. When you try to create an attribute, you create it in an object the name refers. Keywords do not exist in a compiled Python program, and they are used only by lexer/parser.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: many operators have equivalent functions in the `operators` module. The `ast` module defines syntax tree objects that model syntax constructs. So they *could* be, in certain contexts.

Comment: @Martijn, even those objects are not _keywords_.

Comment: @Ellioh: no, but AST objects do *model* the keywords.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: When I was first learning Python, the statement "Everything is an object" confused me. I didn't know the limit of "things" the word "everything" referred to. Only in retrospect is the statement clear. The statement "Everything is an object" is a tautology to people who know what Everything refers to. It is merely confusion to people who don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, functions in Python are objects as everything else:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
>>> def a(): pass
... 
>>> type(a)
<class 'function'>
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType
<class 'function'>
>>> type(a) is types.FunctionType
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, the inheritance hierarchy is firmly rooted at `object`, but in Python 2 things are less clear-cut. While it's true for both version that “everything is an object” the real question is “what type of object”?

So here's a program that it's instructive to run under both versions (I hope).

```
class OldStyle:
    pass

class NewStyle(object):
    pass

old_obj = OldStyle()
new_obj = NewStyle()

print(OldStyle, NewStyle)
print(old_obj, new_obj)
```

To make it easier to see what's going on I simply pasted the program into different interepreters, the output being shown below.

```
airhead:project sholden$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 19 2013, 03:12:29)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class OldStyle:
...     pass
...
>>> class NewStyle(object):
...     pass
...
>>> old_obj = OldStyle()
>>> new_obj = NewStyle()
>>>
>>> print(OldStyle, type(OldStyle))
(<class __main__.OldStyle at 0x105345808>, <type 'classobj'>)
>>> print(NewStyle, type(NewStyle))
(<class '__main__.NewStyle'>, <type 'type'>)
>>> print(old_obj, type(old_obj))
(<__main__.OldStyle instance at 0x10535ff38>, <type 'instance'>)
>>> print(new_obj, type(new_obj))
(<__main__.NewStyle object at 0x105360bd0>, <class '__main__.NewStyle'>)
>>>
```

Versus

```
airhead:project sholden$ python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Nov 19 2013, 03:15:33)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class OldStyle:
...     pass
...
>>> class NewStyle(object):
...     pass
...
>>> old_obj = OldStyle()
>>> new_obj = NewStyle()
>>>
>>> print(OldStyle, type(OldStyle))
<class '__main__.OldStyle'> <class 'type'>
>>> print(NewStyle, type(NewStyle))
<class '__main__.NewStyle'> <class 'type'>
>>> print(old_obj, type(old_obj))
<__main__.OldStyle object at 0x106884c90> <class '__main__.OldStyle'>
>>> print(new_obj, type(new_obj))
<__main__.NewStyle object at 0x106884c50> <class '__main__.NewStyle'>
>>>
```

You will see that there are actually relatively few significant differences between the two outputs, which is to Guido van Rossum's credit as a language designer, because a major departure took place around the time of the 2.2 release.

Focusing on the specifics, in Python 2.x a class that does not inherit from `object` is of type `classobj`, and its instances will be of type(instance). In Python 3.x, however, the class is of type `type`, and the instances are of type `__main__.NewStyle`.

In both versions I believe it is true that there is no object `x` for which the expression `isinstance(object, x)` evaluates to False.